# CSS Divs % widths

Tags: html, css

i need to create CSS divs.

- one up the top for the header (full width)
- one on the left (180px) for the vertical menu
- and one to the right for the main content

the menu on the left will be an iframe and then the one on the right will also be an iframe.

I currently have this code:

```
<style type="text/css">
body,html {
    height:98%;
}
#top-bar {
    width:100%;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #000000;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#left-bar {
    width:170px;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
}
#right-bar {
    margin-left:180px;
    width:auto;
    display:inline;
}
#space {
    width:100px;
    height:120px;
}
</style>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" style="position:fixed;z-index:999;top:0;left:0;background-color:#fff">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="index.php"><img src="http://www.integradigital.co.uk/images/company/logo.png" width="282" height="41" /></a></td>
    <td align="right">Hello <?php echo $_SESSION["forename"]; ?> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="space"></div>

<div id="left-bar"><iframe src="header.php" width="180px" height="480px" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe></div>

<div id="right-bar">
<iframe name="rightiframe" src="dash.php" width="100%" height="480px" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
```

but the right content seems to be going under the left menu

i need the top header (currently in the table) to not move when scrolling and the same for the left menu bar and needs to be % so it can all fit on different size screens.

anyone have any ideas what i can do with it?

Answer (score 0):

To start with, move the styles into a separate style sheet and link to this from the `<head>` of the page. Don't use the `<style>` element because it's a pain to maintain and results in duplication across pages. The `<style>` element should not be in the `<body>` of the page.

Also, don't use tables for layout. It's not semantic.

There's no point making a floated element inline. It won't be inline. If those inline elements weren't floated, the width's you've specified wouldn't be applied. Also, don't use the `style` attribute on elements - use CSS.

These suggestions probably won't fix your specific issue, but everything's a bit of a mess at the moment, so I think you've got bigger issues to fix at this point...

Comment: ok thank you - any ideas what i can do to get it how i need it tho?

Answer (score 0):

Try out with the changes below,

```
<div id="left-bar">
   <iframe src="image.png" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"   scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="right-bar">
   <iframe name="rightiframe" src="image.png" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>

#left-bar {
   width: 20%;
   ........
}
#right-bar {
   width: 80%;
   .......
}
```

Note: Never use tables for the alignment of contents in a page. Always use divs with the css defined in .css file with the proper 'class' property defined for div tags.